# How to create this intent putExtra?

Tags: android, android-intent

I  am tryng to set a alarm by a id of  row in the database. Here is my code to set the inent extra but it gives me a errror at putExtra.

```
public void setReminder(long taskId, Calendar when){
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(helper.getById(id), (long)taskId);
}
```

Here is my Cursor fetching the Id from my database.

```
}
public Cursor getById(String id){
    String [] args = {id};

    return(getReadableDatabase()
        .rawQuery("SELECT _id, title, descrip, taskdatetime, type FROM tasks  WHERE _id = ?", args));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a cursor in an intent. You should read the cursor and make an own datatype of it which you can pass using intents.

```
   i.putExtra(helper.getById(id), (long)taskId);
```

This makes no sense either. I assume your cursor is the actually data? In that case the helper.getById() should be the second parameter and taskId the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`putExtra()` takes the name (a string) and the actual value as inputs.

I doubt `helper.getById(id)` in 
`i.putExtra(helper.getById(id), (long)taskId);`  returns a string.

Check that.

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, Bundle value)
```

Parameters:

- `name` -> The name of the extra data, with package prefix &
- `value` -> The Bundle data value.

Returns:

- Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.

Check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29

Hope I was able to help.